# Aproximacion de numeros en una matriz

Tags: lista, matrices, numpy

Tengo la siguiente matriz:

```
[[-397. -259.  -51. -227. -116. -227.]  
 [ 351.  237.   58.  204.  117.  204.]  
 [-140.  -98.  -25.  -83.  -50.  -83.]]
```

y estoy intentando dejar esta matriz, toda en modulo 29 de la siguiente manera:

```
lista1 = []   
for x in matrizf:      
    x = x%29  
    lista1.append(x)  
c = np.array(lista1).reshape(3,-1)  
print ("-MATRIZ FINAL-")   
print (c)
```

pero me lo imprime asi:

```
[[9.00000000e+00 2.00000000e+00 7.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00
  5.54223334e-13 5.00000000e+00]
[3.00000000e+00 5.00000000e+00 2.90000000e+01 1.00000000e+00
  1.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]
[5.00000000e+00 1.80000000e+01 4.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00
  8.00000000e+00 4.00000000e+00]]
```

Como se dan cuenta me imprime toda la matirz con varios decimales, asi que necesito aproximar esos numeros y como se daran cuenta algunos numeros como el 0 me lo imprime de la siguiente manera 5.54223334e-13.
al final solo necesito que la matriz me quede asi:

```
[[ 9  2  7  5  0  5]  
 [ 3  5  0  1  1  1]  
 [ 5  18 4  4  8  4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar np.around para que le quite los decimales al array, algo así:

```
lista1 = np.around(lista1);
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: funciono muy bien gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, por favor márcala como útil.

Answer (score 0):

Si conviertes tus datos en una matriz de numpy puedes reducir tu código a una forma vectorizada.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(lista1, dtype=int)
# El modulo se aplica a todos los elementos de el numpy array
a = a%29
```